# Typesetting music in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I would be grateful for any help typesetting music in LaTeX.  I've tried to use [MusiXTeX](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/indexmt6.html) but have been very frustrated.

As I understand it, the MusiXTeX notation has a steep learning curve, but I'm OK with that; the notation seems to be well documented.  The hardest part is installation and getting a simple "hello world" example to work.

I'm not committed to MusiXTeX; I'll try anything that works with LaTeX.  But I've tried other alternatives and been equally frustrated with them.

Comment: Good question, I never even managed to get all the necessary packages working correctly in concert, haha get it?

Comment: @Alex I wonder how you didn't get a whole cacophony of troll answers to that low level pun! ;D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/web/)?  It uses its own plaintext notation, but uses TeX for output.  The engine itself uses a whole slew of measures to analyze the music and produce pretty sheet music, so it's automated to a much greater extent than MusixTex is.

Comment: I believe LilyPond was one of the alternatives I tried unsuccessfully to use, but it has been a while and I'm not sure.  I'll give it another chance.

Comment: I haven't used it recently, either.  I do remember that chords were a little frustrating because they don't fit well into a one-dimensional (plaintext) data stream, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I just installed LilyPond and the sample application worked. So far so good!  But I don't see the connection to LaTeX.  It produces a PDF file and a PS file.  Looks like I'd need to keep the source in a separate .ly file and include the output as in image in my LaTeX file. Is that right?

Comment: It once used LaTeX, but does not anymore; either that or lilypond-book may have caused the confusion.

Comment: LilyPond has *nothing* to do with TeX/LaTeX. They can be integrated with lilypond-book, but have no other connection.

Answer (score 20):

[Lilypond has a preprocessor](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-program/LaTeX) called `lilypond-book` that lets you mix LaTeX code with Lilypond code in one source file.

Sample usage: tsst.lytex contains this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin[quote,fragment,staffsize=26]{lilypond}
c' d' e'
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

It also supports inline notation (instead of a display), and reading from external files.

Compile it with `lilypond-book --pdf tsst.lytex`, producing pdf images of each system along with a LaTeX file `tsst.tex` that includes the snippets, which compiles as usual with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks!  It's not obvious from the LilyPond home page that there's any connection to LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

If you have simple notations (folk tunes and the like), something like [ABC](http://abcnotation.com/software.html) might be a good fit.  Simple markup-based notation, but prints to LaTeX.  Wikipedia has a [good example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_notation)

```
X:1
T:The Legacy Jig
M:6/8
L:1/8
R:jig
K:G
GFG BAB | gfg gab | GFG BAB | d2A AFD |
GFG BAB | gfg gab | age edB |1 dBA AFD :|2 dBA ABd |:
efe edB | dBA ABd | efe edB | gdB ABd |
efe edB | d2d def | gfe edB |1 dBA ABd :|2 dBA AFD |]
```

Which produces

[ABC example png http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Legacy_jig.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Legacy_jig.png/700px-Legacy_jig.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [lyluatex](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/blob/master/README.en.md), which uses [lualatex](http://www.luatex.org/).

Sample usage: (compiles with `lualatex -shell-escape DOCUMENT.TEX`)

```
\usepackage{lyluatex}

% include file
\lilypondfile[staffsize=17]{PATH/TO/THE/FILE}

% direct input
\begin{lilypond}
\relative c' { c d e f g a b c }
\end{lilypond}

% short direct input
\lilypond[staffsize=12]{c' d' g'}
```